# What's the thing like a giant spiral stone in the Evangelion 3.0's scenery?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

What is that thing like a giant spiral stone. Thats appear in a scenery of eva movie 3.0 ?
Does anyone know what is that thing exactly ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the script included with the Japanese Blu-ray release it is identified as the Black Moon of Lilith, an object that transported the angel Lilith to Earth. Originally spherical shaped much like the Earth's moon in the original anime, it appears to look more like a version of the Holy Grail in this retelling (tilt your head to the right to see its proper orientation).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very good picture explaining it.

[image]

You have the Black Moon which is the spherical space vehicle that is meant to crash on a planet and seed life. The Spiral is the actual structure inside the black moon, where the passenger resides dormant.
The Geofront is a very small part of the Black Moon that was used as the Nerv HQ.
I understand that the shaft leading to the Terminal Dogma is inside the Spiral leading to Lilith's Chamber.